# Transferred coin from Ledger Live to Sparrow

Tags: ledger-hardware-wallet, sparrow-wallet, coldcard

I transferred my bitcoins from Ledger Live Wallet to Cold Card. When I launch Sparrow, it shows the spent amount from ledger live and the coins received to their respective addresses. Is it expected to show the amount transferred from ledger live as a spent amount?

I dont find the interface of Sparrow as good as Ledger Live

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about your setup? How was the Ledger connected to Sparrow? How does the Cold Card fit into your setup? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I’m using cold card for the first time using sparrow. I used the receive address and put that into my send window while transferring in ledger live

Comment: Are your Ledger and Cold Card both holding the keys for the same wallet? I.e. did you import the same seedphrase in each?

Comment: I did not import the same seed. I have a new seed with my coldcard and I transferred my coins to the recieve address paying a new network fee

Comment: ?can someone please respond to my post

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. For example when you write "is it expected to show the amount " what does "it" refer to? Are you using Sparrow as a front end to Ledger, to Cold Card or to both?

Comment: I transferred the coin from my ledger live wallet to my new cold card. It shows I received the coins but then there is a transaction which shows spent that appears to be a ledger live transaction. Is that sent transaction expected to appear to sparrow as well. I thought it’s a separate wallet so  wasn’t sure how it synced to show that as well

Comment: After receiving the coins on a coldcard, it appears the coins were sent to two new addresses in the blockchain. Is that expected?

Comment: The coins were recieved on the recieve addresses. After 2 hours or so, someone within the blockchain system picked up the coins and sent that to a new address. Is that normal ?

Answer (score 0):

> The coins were recieved on the recieve addresses. After 2 hours or so, someone within the blockchain system picked up the coins and sent that to a new address. Is that normal ?

No, that is not normal.

Comment: I checked and looks like within blockchain it was sent to a change address because my wallet was new. Not sure if there is a way to disable this in coldcard